# Singular Matrix error when implementing Burgers equation

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I'm working on implementing Burger's equation to model the propagation of pressure wave's and I am coming across an error (Singular Matrix error), specifically:

```
     23 J = eval(jac)(x,n,fnon,F,*fnonargs)
     25 
---> 26 delta = np.linalg.solve(J,-F)
     27 x = x + delta
     29 F = eval(fnon)(x,*fnonargs)
    111 def _raise_linalgerror_singular(err, flag):
--> 112     raise LinAlgError("Singular matrix")

LinAlgError: Singular matrix
```

I can't seem to figure out where I am going wrong and what is causing it to do this. Quite new to Python and using Jupyter notebook, would appreciate any insight into this.

I've made the code available here: [solver.py](https://pastebin.com/mVtabP7Y) to provide a reproducible example and also to keep the post shorter and easier to read.

I thought the issue might be to do with the Jacobian function but this seems fine and has worked well on another model I was running.

```
import numpy as np

def Jacobian(x,n,fnon,F0,*fnonargs):
  J = np.zeros((n,n), dtype=np.float64)
  h = 10e-8

  for k in range(0,n):
    xb = copy.copy(x)
    xb[k] = xb[k] + h

    F = eval(fnon)(xb,*fnonargs)

    for i in range(0,n):
        J[i,k] = (F[i] - F0[i]) / h

  return J
```

Comment: Have you looked at `J`?  Do you know what  it means to be `singular`?

Comment: @hpaulj I have looked at J and it seems fine. It's not a zero matrix.